# Fantastic thriller with some horror elements about a town connected to an interdimensional portal to another world that influences the townspeople

Tags: story-identification, novel

15-10 years ago I read a horror/fantastic-thriller novel. It took place in a smallish American town (don't remember which part of the US). The protagonist could be maybe between late twenties up to forty-ish. He had a dog (I think) and a couple of friends in town but seemed kind of a loner.

The town itself was strange, with an interdimensional portal to another world that seems to influence most of the people in town. Some characters (I think bad-guys, but maybe greyish) had an encounter with something bordering to cosmic horror. I remember reading that one of the characters in the encounter didn't want the creatures to slip back to Earth. I remember that they found the creature's eggs and that the mature creatures could fly.

The police in town is corrupt, connected to the interdimensional portals that exists. But at least one senior officer is at least coldly friendly with the protagonist. In the way of "I like you, but if you go down this road I can't protect you"-kind-a-way. So not 100% a dark character but not a good guy.

I first suspected the *Odd Thomas* books by Dean Koontz but it doesn't ring a bell when I read the plot synopsis. The style of the book might be a little Koontz-ish though.

Comment: It sounds vaguely similar to Stephen King's *The Tommyknockers*, but I don't remember any eggs, flying or otherwise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tommyknockers

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen yeah, some elements seems a bit similar. The people that had the encounter did seem like scientist/explorers and were afraid of what they found when they went trough one of the portals

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkfall_(Koontz_novel) doesn't quite match. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_(Koontz_novel) is a bit closer, has a portal and a dog, but no corruption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible answer would be [Seize the Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seize_the_Night_(novel)), second of the Moonlight Bay trilogy (possibly - the third volume is indefinitely delayed) by Dean Koontz, potentially with some elements of the first novel also mixed in.

Matching elements:

It's by Dean Koontz, very much the usual cosmic horror style of work.

The protagonist, Chris Snow, has a genetic disease (Xeroderma Pigmentosa) that causes severe light sensitivity, so he is functionally nocturnal. As a result, he is portrayed as something of a loner (although does appear to know a lot of people - American small town stereotype). Two closest friends are Bobby Halloway and his girlfriend Sasha Goodall. He also has a dog, Orson, implied to be more intelligent than is typical.

The town was strange, largely as a result of experiments on an adjacent, mostly abandoned, army base. Genetic engineering that was changing the residents was the plot of the first novel. The police force is mostly 'changing', and pretty much entirely in on the conspiracy. The police chief, Manuel Ramirez, was a friend of Chris Snow, but is benefiting from the project (increasing the intelligence of his son who has Down's syndrome) and so will act to protect the conspiracy over his previous friendship.

Also on the base is a portal ('the egg room') to another dimension - this was another of the secret projects that was ongoing. Flying creatures in this dimension, looking like demons, shot projectiles into the researchers, which turned out to be eggs allowing the creatures to cross into our world; part of the plot is ensuring they are all destroyed.

Comment: Fantastic - this is it!

Comment: I had thought of that one, but foolishly assumed that I'd already ruled it out with my prior comment. :-D Congrats!

Comment: I think I meant to link https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188483/fantastic-sci-fi-thriller-journalist-investigating-disparitions-near-a-factory/236640#236640

Answer (score 2):

While I don't think it had a portal, this reminds me very much of Watchers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchers_(novel)

Edit: Matching elements are Dean Koontz, cosmic horror, conspiracy, and a dog as a prominent part of the story.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches?

Comment: Doesn't every Dean Koontz book have a dog?